# python + given dataframe series, get index

Tags: python

I am currently working on a function for: dataframe.apply(function, axis=1).

I need to reference the value of the index (ie, 0, 1, 2 etc, whatever the index is in the row that's passed above).

```
def function(row):
    whatstheindex = row.index?
    return whatstheindex
```

I can't figure out to reference that though.  I've tried row['INDEXNAME'], I've tried using:

```
float(row.index.get_loc(row.loc[:,:,row['ROWVALUE']].index[0]))
```

but ROWVALUE is non-unique, and I *think* its returning more than one index? The error I got was:

> IndexingError: ('Too many indexers', u'occurred at index XYZ')

Comment: maybe this post can help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982786/why-does-this-return-too-many-indexers

Comment: I think converting to a numpy array seems a bit overkill?  must be an easier way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `row.name`? The rows are pandas series in the apply function

Comment: that did it! too easy... i knew there had to be some attribute..  Thanks!